# How do I do a multi-project build that outputs a jar for every subproject?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a project, called `Main`, and 2 subprojects: `One`, `Two`. Here's what my `build.sbt` looks like:

```
name := "Main"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))  aggregate(one, two) dependsOn(one, two)
lazy val one = Project(id = "one", base = file("One"))
lazy val two = Project(id = "two", base = file("Two"))
```

when I run `sbt compile package` I only get a `.jar` for `Main` (`Main.jar`), but I want to get a `.jar` for every subproject and not `Main`: `One.jar`, `Two.jar`.

How do I achieve this?

Also I have no idea what `aggregate(one, two) dependsOn(one, two)` means, do I even need that?

I also want every subproject to build into a fat jar with `sbt-assembly`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works now. I was encountering this behavior, where sbt was telling me that my assembly was not packaged, because it was up-to-date, but then I started doing `sbt clean assembly`, instead of `sbt assembly` and it works like a charm now.